# Why is this Keras OneHot layer implementation performing different then OneHot training data?

Tags: python, keras, one-hot-encoding

I want to learn a convnet to classify > 240.000 docs in approx 2000 classes. For this I selected the first 60 words and converted them to indices.
I tried to implement a OneHot layer in Keras to avoid memory issues but the model performs much worse than the model with the data already prepared as OneHot. What is the real difference?

The models summary reports are similar in shape and parameters except for the additional One_hot Lambda layer. I used the One_Hot function described here: https://fdalvi.github.io/blog/2018-04-07-keras-sequential-onehot/

```
def OneHot(input_dim=None, input_length=None): 
# input_dim refers to the eventual length of the one-hot vector (e.g. 
vocab size)
# input_length refers to the length of the input sequence
# Check if inputs were supplied correctly
if input_dim is None or input_length is None:
    raise TypeError("input_dim or input_length is not set")

# Helper method (not inlined for clarity)
def _one_hot(x, num_classes):
    return K.one_hot(K.cast(x, 'uint8'),
                      num_classes=num_classes)

# Final layer representation as a Lambda layer
return Lambda(_one_hot,
              arguments={'num_classes': input_dim},
              input_shape=(input_length,))

# Model A :  This is the Keras model I use with the OneHot function:
model = Sequential()
model.add(OneHot(input_dim=model_max,
                     input_length=input_length))
model.add(Conv1D(256, 6, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3)) 
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(labels_max, activation='softmax'))
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-best.h5', verbose=1, 
monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

#Model B: And this model I use with the data already converted to OneHot:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(256, 6, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_length, 
model_max)))
model.add(Conv1D(64, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(3))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(labels_max, activation='softmax'))
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('model-best.h5', verbose=1, 
monitor='val_loss',save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(),
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Model B is performing much better with validation accuracy up to 60% but it runs easily into memory errors.
Model A is much faster but only reaches a maximum validation accuracy of 25%.
I would expect them to perform similar. What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: I think I see an issue in the size of the datatype 'uint8'. In a different setup I changed this to 'int32' which seem to work.